# Cannot read property 'RNFSFileTypeRegular' of null (for Windows platform)

Tags: react-native, npm, react-native-fs

I installed the `react-native-fs` for my project and got this error right away.

[image]

It is a latest react native for windows application and has the `react-native-fs v. 2.20.0` installed.

- I tried downgrading to *2.19.0* and *2.15.1*.
- Reset Cache.
- Delete `package-lock.json` and `npm install` again.

No luck so far.
Is there anything else I can try?